# In how many ways can 4 distinct chocolates be distributed among three children such that exactly one of the children gets no chocolate?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 4 distinct chocolates be distributed among three children such that exactly one of the children gets no chocolate?

Let's choose two children in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways whom we have to distribute. Total number of ways to distribute four chocolates among them is hence $\binom{3}{2}2^4$. However , in the total ways to distribute 4 chocolates , which is $2^4$ , I've also counted the cases when one of those two children gets no chocolate (which is same as the case when only one child gets all the chocolates). To compensate for that, I subtracted $\binom{3}{1}$ from the total ways. Hence, the correct final answer should be :

$$\binom{3}{2}2^4-\binom{3}{1}=45$$

However, according to answer key, the answer is $42$. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Is is not: $\binom{3}{2}=\frac {3!}{2!}=\frac{3*2*1}{2*1}=3$ and $2^4=16$ and $\binom{3}{1}=\frac{3!}{1!}=3*2$.  But if one does apply the formulas $\text{Ways}=\frac{3!}{2!}*2^4-\frac{3!}{1!}$ then $\text{Ways}=\frac{3*2*1}{2*1}*2*2*2*2-\frac{3*2*1}{1}$ and then $\frac{3*2*1}{2*1}=3$ and $\frac{3*2}{1}=6$ and $2^4=16$ so we would have $3*16-6=48-6=42$!  It seems like you might have some confusion about what the Binomial Coefficient $\binom{\text{ }}{\text{ }}$ is and that might be the source of the difficulty.  See [Binomial Coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html)

Comment: From the Reference for the [Binomial Coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html), $\binom{3}{2}=\frac{3!}{2!*(3-2)!}=\frac{3*2*1}{2*1}=3$.  So that term on the left seems correct.  Here is then the problem with your answer:  **I've also counted the cases when one of those two children gets no chocolate (which is same as the case when only one child gets all the chocolates).**  In the tabled answer, cases where 1 child gets all chocolates are "1,1,1,1", "2,2,2,2", and "3,3,3,3".  For these **not 1, but rather 2 children get no chocolate**. Troubleshot starting there.

Comment: Understand result:  one child out of 3 (child #1, #2, or #3) gets no chocolate.  That means for four chocolates, there are 2 places left.  Each turn for the four chocolates #1 (2 places), #2 (2 places) #3 (2 places) and #4 (two places).  So there are 3*2*2*2*2 possibilities that one child does not get chocolate.  Now *only one* possibilities: subtract 2 children getting no chocolates.  So if child #1 does not get, either #2 or #3 can not.  If child #2 does not, either #1 or #3 does not.  If child #3 does not get, either child #1 or child #2 does not: 6 possibilities. **48-6=42 possibilities**

Comment: @StephenElliott Yes I get it. Thanks 

Comment: See my answer. As you wrote, from the 81 combinations, there are 3 where one child gets all: either child#1, child#2, or child#3.  For 0 children to have no chocolates,  chocolate #1 can go to child #1, #2, or #3; chocolate #2 can go to one of the two remaining children; chocolate #3 is then the leftover child-no choice. Also the possibilities chocolate#2 to child #1, #2, #3;  chocolate #1 to leftover two children.  Shortcut (child # 1, chld #2, child #3)= possibilities (#1 #2 #3)=6 (#2 #1 #3)=6 (#1 #3 #2)=6 (#3 #1 #2)=6  (#2 #3 #1)=6 (#3 #2 #1)=6';  so of 81 total 81-3-6*6=42!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's correct your approach.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select the two children will receive chocolates.  If there were no restrictions, there would be $2^4$ ways to distribute the chocolates to the two selected students.  However, those distributions include two distributions in which only one of the two selected students receives chocolates.  Hence, the number of ways to distribute four distinct chocolates to three children such that exactly one of the children receives no chocolates is
$$\binom{3}{2}(2^4 - 2)$$

Comment: Oops , so It should be two instead of three. And also, I was subtracting it at wrong place. Thanks sir. Can you reference me this principle where it's taught in terms of counting ( and not in terms of set theory) and also in a simple way ?

Comment: I used the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the [Complement Principle](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Complementary_counting) to solve the problem.  All of mathematics is based on set theory, so you will have to develop an understanding of basic set theory (such as the operations intersection, union, set difference, and complement) as you progress deeper into the subject.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow your instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In your process, you choose 2 children ($ab$, $ac$, and $bc$). The combination where $a$ gets all chocolates is counted twice in your process, once when you treat $ab$ and once when you treat $ac$. And same for $b$ and $c$. So, you need to subtract $2 \times 3$ instead of $3$.

The general rule is known as 'Principle of inclusion/exclusion'.

Comment: Thanks. Can you reference me this principle where it's taught in terms of counting ( and not in terms of set theory) and also in a simple way ? I have tried wikipidea and youtube but to no use :(

Comment: All references that I find are based on set theory. For such questions, you can solve intermediate questions : how many ways to distribute 4 distinct chocolates to exactly A and B, A and B given at least one chocolate. And after, multiply by 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by writing out a table of the $3*3*3*3$ combinations of chocolates, and then summing the "yes" entries (copy and paste to a text editor to easily scroll through the combinations or better print the table out). This calculation **results in the answer of 42** for the question, "In how many ways can 4 distinct chocolates be distributed among three children such that exactly one of the children gets no chocolate?".

The table is below:

| Index | Choc #1, Child#= | Choc #2 Child#= | Choc #3 Child#= | Choc #4 Child #= | How Many Not? | Just 1 Child Not Receiving? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | no |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 9 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 11 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 13 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 14 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 15 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 16 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 17 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 18 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 19 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 20 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 21 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 22 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 23 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 24 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 25 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 26 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 27 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 28 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 29 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 30 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 31 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 32 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 33 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 34 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 35 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 36 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 37 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 38 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 39 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 40 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 41 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | no |
| 42 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 43 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 44 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 45 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 46 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 47 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 48 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 49 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 50 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 51 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 52 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 53 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 54 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 55 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 56 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 57 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 58 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 59 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 60 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 61 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 62 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 63 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 64 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 65 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 66 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | no |
| 67 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 68 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 69 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 70 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 71 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 72 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 73 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 74 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | no |
| 75 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 76 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | no |
| 77 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 78 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | yes |
| 79 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 80 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 81 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | no |

Final count of children receiving just one Chocolate (number of Yes entries) is 42.

The table can be also be easily written out by hand since there are only 81 combinations to deal with and these are slightly tedious but easily tractable to resolve with the table method.

Also, generation of the table itself can be facilitated as follows:

```
// Basice Ountline From:  https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/
// Answer to http://https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844397/in-how-many-ways-can-4-distinct-chocolates-be-distributed-among-three-children-s
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

int i; //who receives chocolate #1, child #1 through child #3
int j; //who receives chocolate #2, child #1 through child #3
int k; //who receives chocolate #3, child #1 through child #3
int l; //who receives chocolate #4, child #1 through child #3

int countOnlyOne;
int notChild1;
int notChild2;
int notChild3;
int indexInt;

int main() {
// Write C code here

//Part II of code to generate the table
    // Write C code here
    countOnlyOne=0;
    indexInt=0;
    printf("Starting the Loop on Possibilities: \n");
    printf("| Index | Choc #1, Child#= | Choc #2 Child#= | Choc #3 Child#= | Choc #4 Child #= |  How Many Not? | Just 1 Child Not Receiving? | \n");
    printf("|:-----:|:----------------:|:---------------:|:---------------:|:----------------:|:--------------:|:----------------------------| \n");
    
        for (i=1; i<=3; i++) //Possibilities of distribution of Chocolate #1 to Child 1 through Child 3
        for (j=1; j<=3; j++) //Possibilities of distribution of Chocolate #2 to Child 1 through Child 3
            for (k=1; k<=3; k++) //Possibilities of distribution of Chocolate #3 to Child 1 through Child 3
                for (l=1; l<=3; l++) //Possibilities of distribution of Chocolate #4 to Child 1 through Child 3 
                    {
                    indexInt++;  //Advance the answer counter 
                    //child #1 does not receive => i !=1 && j!=1 && k!=1 && l!=1
                    notChild1 = ((i!=1) && (j!=1) && (k!=1) && (l!=1));
                    //child #2 does not receive => i !=2 && j!=2 && k!=2 && l!=2
                    notChild2 = ((i!=2) && (j!=2) && (k!=2) && (l!=2));
                    //child #3 does not receive => i !=3 && j!=3 && k!=3 && l!=3
                    notChild3 = ((i!=3) && (j!=3) && (k!=3) && (l!=3));
                    //Not More Than 1 Child: notChild1+notChild2+notChild3==1
                    if ((notChild1+notChild2+notChild3)==1) {
                        countOnlyOne++;
                        printf("| %d | %d | %d | %d | %d | 1 | yes |\n",indexInt,i,j,k,l);
                    //printf ("Not More than One Child: notChild1 = %d notChild2= %d notChild3=%d ", notChild1, notChild2, notChild3);
                    //printf("Count %d: Possibility #i=%d j=%d k=%d l=%d is only one child not receiving a chocolate.\n", countOnlyOne, i, j, k, l);
                        }
                    else {
                        printf("| %d | %d | %d | %d | %d | %d | no |\n",indexInt,i,j,k,l,(notChild1+notChild2+notChild3));
                        }

                    
                    }
    printf("\n Final count of children receiving just one Chocolate (number of Yes entries) is %d. \n",countOnlyOne);

                
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are just 3*3*3*3 possible chocolate distributions to sort through.  When I was in the University, it was perfectly legitimate to write out a table of such length and hand sort through the various possibilities. As I remember from [Richard Feyman's book "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter"](https://z-lib.io/book/17562890), there were two ways that the South American Astrologists coud do a calculation, either sorting beans or referencing their Hyrogliphics, each coming to the same answer.  Sure there is a shortcut.  But that does not mean that the original approach is illegitimate

Comment: Your result doesn't seem confirming. Unfortunately, I can't find why because I don't know C.

Comment: @An_Elephant :  I updated the answer to now include a table which **does not require any programming knowledge what so-ever**.  Each "yes" entry can be checked by hand.  And after that all of the "yes" entries can be summed by hand.  I summed all of the "yes" entries in the table by hand and I now also come to the answer of 42. I recommend solving the answer by table by hand first.  Then the "shortcut" is a lot easier, because of lesser-effort by far involved.  However, now that there is this table in the answer, the assumptions of shortcut math answer can be checked.  Troubleshoot like this.

Comment: [http://www.stackprinter.com](http://www.stackprinter.com) can be used to preview the result in an easy-to-read fashion.   It is easy to scroll "yes" by "yes" with the index number to tally all of the "yes" results to 42.  Select the StackExchange **mathematics** site and answer ID **4844397**.  It also makes the question and answers a lot easier to review and print-out.